# Put a gap/break in a line plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data set with effectively "continuous" sensor readings, with the occasional gap.

However there are several periods in which no data was recorded.  These gaps are significantly longer than the sample period.

By default, pyplot connects each data point to the next (if I have a line style set), however I feel that this is slightly misleading when it connects the two data points either side of a long gap.

I would prefer to simply have no line there; that is, I would like the line to stop and to start again after the gap.

I have tried adding in an element in these gap sections with the y-value `None`, but seems to send the line back to an earlier part of the plot (though strangely these lines don't appear at all zoom levels).

The other option I have thought of is to simply plot each piece with a separate call to `plot`, but this would be a bit ugly and cumbersome.

Is there a more elegant way of achieving this?

Edit:  Below is a minimal working example demonstrating the behaviour.  The first plot is the joining line I am trying to avoid.  The second plot shows that adding a `None` value appears to work, however if you pan the view of the plot, you get what is shown in the third figure, a line jumping to an earlier part of the plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t1 = np.arange(0, 8, 0.05)
t2 = np.arange(10, 14, 0.05)
t = np.concatenate([t1, t2])
c = np.cos(t)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.plot(t, c)
ax.set_title('Undesirable joining line')


t1 = np.arange(0, 8, 0.05)
t2 = np.arange(10, 14, 0.05)
c1 = np.cos(t1)
c2 = np.cos(t2)
t = np.concatenate([t1, t1[-1:], t2])
c = np.concatenate([c1, [None,], c2])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.plot(t, c)
ax.set_title('Ok if you don\'t pan the plot')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca()
ax.plot(t, c)
ax.axis([-1, 12, -0.5, 1.25])
ax.set_title('Strange jumping line')

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot 3, the "strange jumping line"]

Comment: Would it be possible to make a reproducible example, especially showing the matplotlib code you are currently using to plot?

Comment: Good idea.  Added the example.

Comment: What if you call plot() twice? Ie. ax.plot(t1,c1) and ax.plot(t2,c2). You have to set the color manually: ax.plot(t1, c1, c = "b")

Comment: I tried your code (python 3.3, matplotlib 1.2.1) and don't see your "Strange jumping line" in the third figure… by the way, you can just write c = np.sin(t).

Comment: PhML, thanks for trying that.  Looks like tom10 below doesn't experience it on his machine either, so perhaps it is just my set-up.

Answer (score 16):

Masked arrays work well for this.  You just need to mask the first of the points you don't want to connect:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t1 = np.arange(0, 8, 0.05)
mask_start = len(t1)
t2 = np.arange(10, 14, 0.05)
t = np.concatenate([t1, t2])
c = np.cos(t)     # an aside, but it's better to use numpy ufuncs than list comps

mc = ma.array(c)
mc[mask_start] = ma.masked
plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, mc)
plt.title('Using masked arrays')

plt.show()
```

[image]

At least on my system (OSX, Python 2.7, mpl 1.1.0), I don't have any issues with panning, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  On my machine (Python 2.7.3, matplotlib 1.1.1) I still get the unwanted line if I pan the plot.

Comment: Works great, also in connection with a `pandas.DataFrame`

Comment: Is there a way to do this easily that you don't lose the masked data point?  Can you easily insert a point between len(t1) and the next point, then mask that?  I would like to do this with data that I would like to insert multiple breaks.  This looks like a useful solution if I can keep all of my data.

Comment: @Shawn: Sure, you can insert a point wherever you want, and mask that (I don't think you'll need to insert "the next point" but I may not understand what you're going for). Or, of course, you could just plot the curves separately. Otherwise, I would suggest asking a separate question, because what you are looking for is different than the original question.

Comment: @tom10: This answer doesn't draw the point at t=10, which can be easily seen by zooming in or removing the 0.05 step size. To draw all points using masking, some ugliness like the concatenate in the question is needed. Avoiding the ugliness by discarding points is not a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

The strange lines were a bug in matplotlib 1.1.1.

There is no need to have the `t` component of the dummy points in chronological order, zero values will also work.

For the `c` component, I use `np.nan` instead of `None`, which (on conversion from a list) forces the `dtype` to `'float64'` instead of `'O'` (object).

Dummy points are best inserted at the time of filling the array with samples (or appending to a list), like so:

```
samples = [] # (t,c) data pairs.
# Waiting for samples in a loop.
    if samples and current_sample[0] > samples[-1][0] + GAP_TOLERANCE:
        samples.append((0, np.nan))
    samples.append(current_sample)

t, c = np.array(samples).T
```