# Putting a gap/break in a pyplot line plot without losing data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a time series with several large data gaps.  I would like to see a connecting line between data points that are less than an hour apart, but not if the gap is larger.  The accepted answer to the question, [Put a gap/break in a line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652503/put-a-gap-break-in-a-line-plot), would work except that you sacrifice the masked points.  I would like to avoid that.

I have attempted to make a list comprehension that would insert NaNs into the array, I think that would automatically achieve the same result, but I don't seem to be able to do it correctly.  The best I have found is as follows:

```
import datetime as dtm
import numpy    as np

x = np.array([dtm.datetime(2001,4,3,0,47,30),dtm.datetime(2001,4,3,0,52,30),dtm.datetime(2001,4,3,0,57,30),dtm.datetime(2001,4,3,3,57,30),dtm.datetime(2001,4,3,4,2,30),dtm.datetime(2001,4,3,4,7,30)])

xmod = np.array([x[0]]+[dt1 if dt1-dt0 < dtm.timedelta(hours=1.) else [dt1,np.nan] for dt1, dt0 in zip(x[1:],x[:-1])])
```

This gives the result:

```
In [7]: xmod
Out[7]: 
   array([datetime.datetime(2001, 4, 3, 0, 47, 30),
   datetime.datetime(2001, 4, 3, 0, 47, 30),
   datetime.datetime(2001, 4, 3, 0, 52, 30),
   [datetime.datetime(2001, 4, 3, 0, 57, 30), nan],
   datetime.datetime(2001, 4, 3, 3, 57, 30),
   datetime.datetime(2001, 4, 3, 4, 2, 30)], dtype=object)
```

I have not been able to find a way to insert both the data point and the np.nan without putting brackets around them.  Is this possible?  Is there a better way to achieve my goal?  Thanks!

Comment: What about splitting your data set into a list of sub-sets? You will be able to plot each set separately and gaps will occur naturally. You just need to find a proper way of splitting (when data points are more than 1 hour apart).

Comment: @taras I think that your approach is probably the appropriate method.  It was probably not intended for list comprehensions to add two consecutive elements at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance with the comment above, probably the easiest way to do this would be to separate the data into groups where you need the gaps. Here is one way to implement such a thing.

```
import datetime as dtm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = np.array([dtm.datetime(2001,4,3,0,47,30),dtm.datetime(2001,4,3,0,52,30),dtm.datetime(2001,4,3,0,57,30),
              dtm.datetime(2001,4,3,3,57,30),dtm.datetime(2001,4,3,4,2,30),dtm.datetime(2001,4,3,4,7,30)])

y = range(len(x))

# make a dataframe with groups separated that are over an hour apart
data = []
g = 0
for i in range(len(x)):
    x0 = x[i]
    y0 = y[i]
    if i < (len(x)-1):
        x1 = x[i+1]
        td = x1 - x0
        elapsed_seconds = td.total_seconds()
        hrs = (elapsed_seconds/60)/60
        if hrs < 1:
            data.append([x0,y0, g])
        else:
            data.append([x0,y0, g])
            g+=1
    else:
        data.append([x0,y0, g])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x', 'y', 'group'])

# draw a plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize = (8,5))
for i, dfg in df.groupby('group'):

    ax.plot(dfg['x'], dfg['y'], c='b')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, I accepted the answer by djakubosky because it seems clean and is probably the right approach.  However, by the time that answer was posted, I had decided that what I was doing was inappropriate for a list comprehension and simply wrote it as a for loop - and that worked fine.  Possibly this will be useful to someone else.  Here is the code:

```
def insert_breaks(x,y):
    import datetime as dtm
    import numpy    as np

    xnew = []
    ynew = []
    for dt1, dt0, y1, y0 in zip(x[1:],x[:-1],y[1:],y[:-1]):
        if dt1-dt0 < dtm.timedelta(hours=1):
            xnew+=[dt0]
            ynew+=[y0]
        else:
            xnew+=[dt0,dt0+(dt1-dt0)/2]
            ynew+=[y0, np.nan]

    xnew+=[dt1]
    ynew+=[y1]

    return xnew, ynew
```