# how to avoid having lines drawn between non-contiguous data in matplotlib.pyplot.plotfile

Tags: matplotlib

I am using matplotlib.pyplot.plotfile to read and plot data from a comma-separated-file.
The file has a number of locations where rows are missing (on purpose). I want the plot to stop at this point, lift the pen, and restart a new line after the break. Instead it is always ignoring the missing line, and joining the data points to make a continuous plot. Can I stop this from happening?

Comment: See [this example code](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/pylab_examples/masked_demo.html)

Comment: Also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15652503/put-a-gap-break-in-a-line-plot)

Comment: thanks, I'll give this a try tomorrow

Comment: From [`plotfile` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plotfile.html) _"Note: plotfile is intended as a convenience for quickly plotting data from flat files; it is not intended as an alternative interface to general plotting with pyplot or matplotlib."_ — or, what you want to do cannot be done using `plotfile`